# 2 column lay out - Image does not take full height of it container

Tags: css, image, elementor

I had created a 2 column layout -
1 text column, 1 image column.

The image is set to 100%, and its 2000 px 2000px.
At first, it takes 100% of its container, but when I add more content to the second column (and therefor - expanding the height) -
The image does not take the full height and width of its container.

I am using WordPress btw.

I attach an image - to show my example.
[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVQ1j.jpg)

*Both of the columns are in the same container/section.

**First example -**
Image is taking 100% of its container.

**Second example -**
Adding more content to the next column - making it higher :

The image remains the same height.

How can I fix it, making the image take 100% of its container even If I adding more content?

Comment: use a div and give background to the div and the property of background-size to cover this with no-repeat and position center center if you want that

`background: url('your image url here') no-repeat center center/cover;`